# How to throw from the finally clause an exception caught in the catch clause?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

Is it possible **without using an additional variable** to find out what exception was caught in the catch clause and then throw it again from the finally clause?

```
public void exceptionalFunction() throws Exception
 {
    try
     {
         // exception causing code
     }
    catch (TypeAException e)
     {
        // exception specific logic
     }
    catch (TypeBException e)
     {
         // exception specific logic        
     }
    catch (TypeCException e)
     {
        // exception specific logic        
     }
    finally
     {
         // throw the exception that was caught, if one was caught. 
     }
 }
```

Comment: finally executes ir-respective of catch block (with throw), then why do you want to throw it again in finally?

Comment: "without using an additional variable" sounds like a totally arbitrary requirement... can you explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @mellamokb If I catch 10 different exceptions, I don't want to write code in each of them.

Comment: The answer is no. There are a number of ways to do a number of things, but there isn't a way to know, in the finally block, which exception was thrown (if any) except using a variable.

Comment: Err, don't catch it at all? Throw it *from the catch block*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not without using an additional variable. Without using an additional variable you could only throw again the exception after the exception specific logic:

```
catch (TypeAException e)
{
    // exception specific logic 
    throw e;       
}
catch (TypeBException e)
{
    // exception specific logic 
    throw e;       
}
catch (TypeCException e)
{
    // exception specific logic 
    throw e;       
}
```

Comment: But I doubt that we can catch them in the finally clause... That was the question.

Comment: @Andreas_D Yes, I know. But only one of his requirements can be achieved, and I think this is the clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot catch them in the finally clause. the scope of catch and finally are separate. But since you do not want to write multiple exception handling codes, I'd suggest you use the features introduced in Java 7.

```
....
....
catch (Exception1|Exception2|Exception2 e){
    //determine type and handle accordingly
}
```

If you are using java6 or earlier, the only way to save coding efforts is to handle them via a method.

```
....
....
catch(Exception1 e){
    handle(e);
}
catch(Exception2 e){
    handle(e);
}
```

then you can use instanceof to determine the type of exception and do your thing.

Comment: There is an excellent tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with tibtof.

It makes no sense to re-throw the exception in a finally block versus doing it after the implementation logic of each catch block - you gain nothing by doing so.  So his is the correct solution.

Generally speaking it is better to do it in this manner as you can extend this by declaring more specific exceptions each time and passing these back up the call stack each time - by creating your own custom exception type and doing:

```
catch (TypeAException e) 
{ 
    // exception specific logic  
    throw new myCustomException("Custom message " + e.getMessage);      
}
```

each time.

Hope that helps.